# If there are multiple <i> tags for a single line of text, is there a way to wrap the text in only one <i> tag?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am working with a very rough html file here.

It looks something like:

```html
<p><i><font size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;font-style:italic;"> The
    Company’s future results</font></i><i><font size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;font-style:italic;">
    and energy,</font></i><i><font style="font-style:italic;">including oil
    and natural gas</font></i><i><font style="font-style:italic;">are under risk</font></i>Some text in the p tag</p>
```

The text `The Company's future results and energy, including oil and natural gas are under risk` is in multiple `<i>` tags

Is there a way that I can get just one `<i>` around this text. (I don't care about the font tag). My html should look something like this:

```html
<p><i><font size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;font-style:italic;"> The
    Company’s future results</font><font size="2" style="font-size:10.0pt;font-style:italic;">
    and energy,</font><font style="font-style:italic;">including oil
    and natural gas</font><font style="font-style:italic;">are under risk</font></i>Some text in the p tag</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use regular expressions to do that.
Like:

```
import re
html= re.sub(r'</i><i>', '', html, flags=re.I)
```

Of course, if you are sure, that the i-tag is always written in lower case, you could simply do:

```
html= html.replace('</i><i>', '')
```

Both versions rely on the assumption, that the opening and closeing i-tag appear next to each other in order to be replaced (but I guess that's what you want, right?).